# Constructor DI in Singleton

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, dependency-injection

I need use `Map control` in `ViewModel` (this contradicts the MVVM and I'm not sure what need, but that is another question).

I use `Dependency Injection` pattern, implementing constructor injection

**IMapService interface**

```
public interface IMapService
{
     Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map Map
     {
        get;           
     }
}
```

**ViewModelLocator**

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public MeetingsViewModel Meetings
        {
            get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MeetingsViewModel>(); }
        }    

        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);            
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MeetingsViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MeetingsViewModel   
{
    private ObservableCollection<MeetingViewModel> _meetings;
    public ObservableCollection<MeetingViewModel> Meetings
    {
        get { return _meetings; }
        set
        {
           _meetings = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("Meetings");
        }
    }    

    private readonly IMapService _mapService;


    public MeetingsViewModel(IMapService mapService)
    {
        _mapService = mapService;
        _mapService.Map.ResolveCompleted += (s, e) => ClusterHelper.RenderPins(Meetings, _mapService.Map);  //render pushpins 
    }

    //...
}
```

**View**

```
public partial class Meeting : PhoneApplicationPage, IMapService
    {
        private ViewModelLocator viewModelLocator = new ViewModelLocator();

        public Meeting()
        {
            InitializeComponent();      
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMapService>(() => this);
            this.DataContext = viewModelLocator.Meetings;
        }

        public Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map Map
        {
            get { return MyMap; } // return Map control
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
           base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
           SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<IMapService>();               
        }
    }
```

But if I have `Singleton ViewModel` what way is better for constructor injection in `Instance` property?

```
static MeetingsViewModel instance = null;

public static MeetingsViewModel Instance
{
   get
   {
       lock (padlock)
       {
          if (instance == null)
          {
              instance = new MeetingsViewModel(); 
          }
          return instance;
       }
   }
}
```

**ViewModelLocator**

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public MeetingsViewModel Meetings
        {
            get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MeetingsViewModel>(); }
        }    

        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);            
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MeetingsViewModel>(() => MeetingsViewModel.Instance);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a singleton in your code? If you need an object of singleton lifetime, your DIContainer will probably be able to provide this without implementing an anti-pattern manually.

Comment: I have "step by step" wizard, few Views have one ViewModel. Singleton is very comfortable in this case.

Comment: A singleton is next to impossible to unit test and I don't seen any comfort that a singleton would offer over a normal global variable.

Comment: No as nvoigt said you don't need the singleton just call SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MeetingsViewModel>() from code to access the single MeetingsViewModel. Also you should register the service in ViewModelLocator